# Script to crop image is failing due to undefined variable after I did some refactoring to my code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello friends from the world. I have been looking to make this script work, it is intended to help crop an image using coordinates, this but apparently something is failing.
Im pretty new to javascript and jQuery but I think I almost got it.

Im getting undefined errors on my value (v) variable.

```
portada_next.on("click", function () {
    if(portada_uploader.isValid && !portada_uploader.isEmpty){
        portada_next.parents(".carousel").carousel("next");
        $.each(portada_uploader.inputs, function (v,k) {
            let img = $(v.previewer.img).clone();
            img.addClass("img-fluid");
            $("#crop").append(img);
            const nw = img.get(0).naturalWidth;
            const nh = img.get(0).naturalHeight;
            img.Jcrop({
                minSize: 0,
                aspectRatio: 2,
                setSelect: [ 0, img.height()/2, nw,nh],
                allowResize: true,
                allowSelect: false,
                trueSize: [nw,nh],
                onChange: function (coords) {
                    my_coords = coords;
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

This script was working before some refactoring that was done, but as I lost track of the changes I don't know that has changed.

Comment: well, the only way `v` can be undefined is if one of the values in `portada_uploader.inputs` is undefined - `console.log(portada_uploader.inputs)` and check the values

Comment: You are right, after checking alessandro's answer the script is working. The undefined problem came from other part but now its fixed. Thanks a lot for your help @JaromandaX

Comment: so, it wasn't `v` that was undefined, it was `v.previewer` that was undefined - because you had k and v swapped ... I bet the error wasn't saying v is undefined, rather that v.previewer was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I think I found your problem, you are using key instead of value, thats why your script is failing.

This line: `$.each(portada_uploader.inputs, function (k,v) {` is saying v (value), k (key) but it should be inversed.
Test this and then check if it works.

```
portada_next.on("click", function () {
    if(portada_uploader.isValid && !portada_uploader.isEmpty){
        portada_next.parents(".carousel").carousel("next");
        $.each(portada_uploader.inputs, function (k,v) {
            let img = $(v.previewer.img).clone();
            img.addClass("img-fluid");
            $("#crop").append(img);
            const nw = img.get(0).naturalWidth;
            const nh = img.get(0).naturalHeight;
            img.Jcrop({
                minSize: 0,
                aspectRatio: 2,
                setSelect: [ 0, img.height()/2, nw,nh],
                allowResize: true,
                allowSelect: false,
                trueSize: [nw,nh],
                onChange: function (coords) {
                    my_coords = coords;
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```